# svn - copy part of repository + history into folder in a different repository?

Tags: svn

I have a repository containing several old projects that I need to move into a folder (not the repo root) in an existing repository. I need to migrate the full history, as well.

svnsync *almost* does what I need, but not quite: as far as I can tell, it won't sync into a folder other than the repository root. I do not have remote desktop access to the machine hosting the source repository, so using svndump is out.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get a dump then svnsync to a new repository, then use `svndumpfilter` to isolate the branches you want, and `svnadmin load` to the final repo location.  Obviously quite inefficient.

Comment: Hmmm... is `svndumpfilter` going to require local drive access to the repo?

Comment: Indirectly, yes.  `svndumpfilter` only acts on a dump, which you only can obtain with full access. Thus you need to svnsync to a new local repo first if you can't get access to the repo any other way.

Comment: svnrdump since svn 1.7 seems to be able to solve this.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.load.html